# Primefaces datatable sort on list

Tags: java, primefaces

i started using primefaces in my project and i have problems right away. I have list with some stuff that i fetch from db with entity manager and i present it in the view in primefaces datatable. In my backing bean i have: List getList() where i retrieve the records from the db with the entity manager and return it right away..

and myService:

```
public List<MyEntity> getDataList(){
  return entityManager.createNamedQuery("MyEntity.getAll").getResultList();
}
```

my bean:

```
public List<MyEntity> getList(){
  return myService.getDataList();
}
```

the view:

```
<p:dataTable var="myEntityInstance" value="#{myBean.list}"...
```

This way primefaces sort was not working, and i read somewhere on stack that the list needs to be member of my backing bean which is wierd i think.. This enforces me to keep my bean sessionScoped which is not very good approach since im hogging the server's memory loading my objects and keeping them alive throughout the session, besides this, there is much more overhead in keeping the lists updated because i must do it manually whenever i make a request to the view. My list is fetched when the first request for that page is made in the @PostConstruct annotated method.. afterwards i need to keep it up to date..
I need know if there is any other way around to get the list directly from the db and give it to primefaces and not keeping it in the bean? So far i'm not satisfied with what primefaces offers.. The design is quite good but there are lots of bugs in the functionality. I have similar problems with other components in it and i find dirty fixes but it bothers me having complexity over simplicity.

Comment: @Bhavik: what a **poor** edit. This post has many more issues open for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Editing aside,

The problem here is that your list is being refreshed from the entity each time it is sorted. Because of the way the framework is set up each time the UI refreshes after a sort you're pulling a new list.

Basically you're seeing -> (and this is not accurate its a sketch of what it is doing)

```
  UI -> sort(myBean.getList());
  UI -> redraw(myBean.getList());
```

Looking at this it means you have two different references, you sort reference #1 then discard it and get a new reference to render. Hence your sorting doesn't work.

The solution is to use a member that you can reference after sorting. This isn't a huge problem as you can use a View Scope instead of a Session or Request scope. Memory wise, you're right to think about it, but you're probably over-optimizing as you're losing features.

In short the fix is->

```
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean
{
  private List<T> myList;
  public List<T> getMyList()
  {
    if(myList != null)
      return myList;
    myList = Service.getMyList();
    return myList;
  }
}
```

Because you can now sort the list and maintain a reference the component will work. If you actually run into memory problems then you can start going down the path of optimization which would be to perform the sort on the service end, create a new list that is sorted based on the call and return than under a request scope. Primefaces allows you to do that, but try the simple method first.

//-----------In response to the nit-picking (because I have the time today and it is interesting...)--------/

I'm not trying to be hostile with you. If you're at that scale why wouldn't you implement a custom component to handle it based on your memory load? Obviously there's an abstraction between an entity and the database itself so implement custom sorting so your `getData()` method would be able to return the correct sorted set as opposed to the maintained reference. Obviously Primefaces (and most JSF implementations) maintain references (stateful) thus you'd need a low-memory solution.

It would probably look something like ->

```
@RequestScoped
public class LessMemoryBean
{
  public List<T> getList()
  {
    StatefulBean state = getStatefulBean();
    //Some switch/case or other method of determining state
    return service.getSortedList(state.getState()); //I like hashmaps, but anything could work.
  }
}

@ViewScoped
public class StatefulBean
{
  private HashMap<String, Boolean> state;
  public void sortField(String key, boolean sortBy)
  {
    state.put(key, sortBy); //Construct the proper query via the keys provided
  }
}

//XHTML
<p:dataTable value="#{lessMemoryBean.data}">
  <!-- Whatever you need -->
  <p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
      <p:commandButton 
        //Do whatever control method you want for sorting and setting booleans
      />
    </f:facet>
  </p:column>
....
```

Because you're using a reference to the RequestScoped bean and that bean references the ViewScoped your list is stored in the request (disposed of ASAP) but the state of the table is separated. Obviously that's not out of the box, Primefaces supports some listeners but you'd need to dig deeper (RTFM) to see what your options are. Also, it is open source so you could simply extend the table to use a listener as an option as opposed to a simple link to a `Collection`.

You're talking optimization which, in my opinion, means you need to do a lot of extra work. Have at it ***(personally I'd use a standard data-table or just implement my own composite component in this situation. It wouldn't be that much work 1-2 days max).***

Comment: Thanks for your efforts to explain me all of this. Again, i have a question.. Why prime can't just take the list reference, sort it and use the same one to pass to the drawing method.. It is a bit confusing to me that prime tries to fetch the list again from the bean and draw it upon the sort.. The reference that i return from my method is there in memory anonymously, and prime can reference the same one for its actions.

Comment: What i'm actually saying is this:

UI: List<T> theList = bean.getList();
UI: sort(theList);
UI: draw(theList);

I think this is simple and workable algorithm. This would allow me to use request scoped bean and have the sort working. As i understand it now, prime requires me to keep a list reference for his actions, and he is strictly relying to me methods to fetch the same list. This i don't like, i don't know what is the idea behind its workings but i just don't like it =)

Comment: Like it or not, that's the implementation. It has to store a reference to the list somewhere and that means it is either managed by your bean or managed by your framework. This seems like the correct implementation to me. It is simple, it is easy to manage the scope and it allows for minimal code to implement some pretty powerful features. Think of it this way: if your request data outlives the scope of the request it isn't request scoped, is it?

Comment: I don't want my data to outlive the scope, it does so because prime's sort feature. I want the items to be fetched from db every-time i make request and present them in a sorted manner. This i can do if i use criteria from JPA and couple of commandLinks that make dynamic query based on what is clicked (and i might go for that one at the end) but i started with prime so i asked for other way to do this sort stuff..

Comment: What if i have 1000 items and i have 1000 users on average. And say one object in the list takes up to 100B, that is 1000^2 * 100B ~ 97656.25MB ~ 97GB.. This speaks of the low scalability and the memory hog. This is huge amount of RAM i need on the server in order to keep my app running and holding 1000 user sessions.. and just think that i might keep other lists as well which can have many items.. This is clearly not good solution to me.. That is why db exists in the first place, not just to store stuff permanently but to free of server memory hog (prove me wrong).

Comment: I've responded to your comment above, I'd sum it up as there isn't a magic bullet for huge scale applications. You'd need to rethink the design. I know I wouldn't outsource something of that scale to a component kit.

Comment: Thanks anyway, i know that when it comes to specifics i need to redesign stuff but before i do so i need to know if such thing is not existent already. =)

This question has been resolved, thanks Daniel!